# KnpMenuBundle and dynamic route parameter

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, routes, knpmenubundle

i use knpmenubundle for my website and here is my problem :
i've a list of user listed by this route : /admin/users
and the menu is like this :

```
User (is opened)
    list (is active)
    add new
```

in the list view, the item "**list**" in the menu is active like i want
in the add new view, the item "**add new**" in the menu is active like i want

but, when i want to edit an user which allready exist, i can't manage to active the item "**Users**" because te route have a dynamic parameter

here is how my site is structured :

**in src/dn/AdminBundle/Resources/Config/routing.yml**

```
# Users
### List
dnAdmin_usersList:
    pattern: /users/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: dnAdminBundle:User:list, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d*

### Edit
dnAdmin_userEdit:
    pattern: /user/edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: dnAdminBundle:User:edit}
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

**in app/ressources/view/layout/html/twig**

```
{{ render(controller("dnAdminBundle:Common:leftMenu")) }}
```

**in src/dn/AdminBundle/Controller/CommonController**

```
public function leftMenuAction()
{
    return $this->render('dnAdminBundle:Common:leftMenu.html.twig');
}
```

**in src/dn/AdminBundle/Resources/view/Common/leftMenu/html.twig**

```
{{ knp_menu_render('leftMenu', {'template':'dnAdminBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig', 'currentClass':'active', 'ancestorClass':'active'}) }}
```

**in src/dn/AdminBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    dn_admin.menu_builder:
        class: dn\AdminBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

    dn_admin.menu.leftMenu:
        class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
        factory_service: dn_admin.menu_builder
        factory_method: createLeftMenu
        arguments: ["@request"]
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: leftMenu }
```

**in src/dn/AdminBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php**
namespace dn\AdminBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;

```
/**
 * @param FactoryInterface $factory
 */
public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

public function createLeftMenu(Request $request)
{
    // root
    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
    $menu->setChildrenAttributes(array('class' => 'sidebar-menu'));

    // Users
    $l = $menu->addChild('Users', array(
        'uri'    => '#',
    ));
    $l->setAttribute('class', 'treeview');
    $l->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'treeview-menu');
    $l->addChild('Liste', array(
        'route'  => 'dnAdmin_userList',
    ));
    $l->addChild('Edit', array(
        'route'           => 'dnAdmin_userEdit',
        'routeParameters' => $request->get('id'),
    ))
    ->setDisplay(false);
}
```

but **$request->get('id')** return empty string

Anyone have idea on how i can get the current parameter in knpmenubundle?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If your menu builder extends ContainerAware you should be able to access the request object. Example:

```
class Builder extends ContainerAware {
public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options) {        

    $request = $this->container->get('request');        

    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
    $parent = $menu->addChild('Users', array('route' => 'users'));
    $parent->addChild('Edit', array('route' => 'user_edit', 'routeParameters' => array('id' => $request->get('id'))));

    return $menu;
}
```

Your Users menu item should get the current_ancestor class

Answer (score 3):

If your menu builder class does not extend ContainerAware (and, as a service, there's no need for it to do so) you can pass in the `@request_stack`, or typehinting `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack` service, and fetch the id from there:

```
$id - $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('id');
// -or- 
$request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
$id = $request->get('id');
```